# postgres: generate series of timestamps respecting time zone

Tags: postgresql

I'm stumped by a tricky issue regarding time zone changes from daylight savings to non daylight savings.

I'm trying to generate a series of timestamps, 6 hrs apart. This is later joined with data with corresponding timestamps at the 00, 06, 12, 18 hrs for each day in the dataset.

This works fine normally, using:

`generate_series(extract(epoch from start_ts)::integer, extract(epoch from end_ts)::integer, 21600)`

where start_ts is 00 hr on the first date, and end_ts is 00 hr on the last date exclusive.

However, when timezone offset goes from +11 to +10 half way through the series, it will no longer match any records since the series elements become 1 hr off.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to generate a series of 'epoch integers' or timestamps which would match 00,06,12,18 hr timestamps while respecting the timezone's offset?

Answer (score 2):

This will generate it (using PostgreSQL 9.5+), starting from today and for 10 days:

```
select (current_date::timestamp + ((a-1)||' days')::interval)::timestamptz
from generate_series(1, 10, .25) a
```

Test it on a whole year:

```
select *, date_part('hour', d::timestamp), d::timestamp
from (
  select (current_date::timestamp + ((a-1)||' days')::interval)::timestamptz AS d
  from generate_series(1, 365, .25) a
  ) x
where date_part('hour', d) not in (0, 6, 12, 18)
```

***Edit***: The version below works with versions of PostgreSQL older than 9.5:

```
select (current_date::timestamp + (((a-1)/4.0)||' days')::interval)::timestamptz
from generate_series(1, 4*  10  ) a  -- 10 days
```

Comment: i like it! seems like we're using 9.4 though, not 9.5 which introduced 'numeric' argument types to the generate_series, prior to that only int/bigint allowed. i'll see if we can upgrade. thx! I did however manage to solve it in a bit more long winded way; generating 2x series - 1 going forward 1 going backward, and then validating each result with. I will post as solution as well since it has some other benefits `to_timestamp(val) at time zone z`.

Comment: sorry, removed tick since further testing shows this does not take timezone into account when the timezone changes to/from DST

Answer (score 0):

@Ziggy's answer is great, use that. however here's how I solved it in my application which can't use decimals in generate_series (v9.4):

```
_min timestamp with time zone, -- the first timestamp in the series
_max timestamp with time zone, -- the last timestamp in the series
_inc integer, -- the increment in seconds, eg 21600 (6hr)
_tz text
```

1. creates a series from the _max down using the tz offset of the _max,
2. creates a series from the _min up using the tz offset of the _min,
3. merges the results
4. validates each result is divisible by the _inc in the tz of the result, discards if not

query:

```
select t1 from (
    select ser,
        to_timestamp(ser) t1,
        extract(epoch from
                to_timestamp(ser) at time zone _tz
                    - date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(ser) at time zone _tz)
            )::integer % _inc = 0 is_good
    from (
        select 'ser1' s, generate_series(extract(epoch from _min)::integer, extract(epoch from _max)::integer, _inc) ser
        union all
        select 'ser2' s, generate_series(extract(epoch from _max)::integer, extract(epoch from _min)::integer, _inc * -1) ser
    ) x
    group by ser, _tz, _inc
    order by ser asc
) x
where is_good 
;
```